# grab file from php which forced to save as from another web server php with http authentication

Tags: php, curl, http-authentication

1. i have a url from another server which having http auth enabled.
2. this specific url forces file to download a file.
3. I am trying here to grab the headers and set the headers back so that i can force the download from my php file after http auth done in curl, but no success. curl did not gave any error. nothing returned in $body.

   ```
   $url=$_GET["url"];//another web server url which forcing file download save as
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");//http auth done here
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   list ($headerString, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
   $headers = explode("\r\n", $headerString);
   foreach ($headers as $header) {
       header($header);
   }
   echo $body;
   exit;
   ```

Comment: Could you please rephrase step 2. and 3.? I don't get what you are trying to do. Also please be more specific about "no success" - any error messages? `curl_error()` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code above is working fine. Issue is just & in the $_GET["url"] which splitting valid url. just used **urlencode** and code working fine now. Hope this will help someone.